# Flask, get value from checkbox and pass the result to another template

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, if-statement, flask

I am using Weasyprint, to display some jinja templates in a Flask Web App. 
I have this json.

```
value=["1","2","3","4"]
```

I want to pass 'value' to another jinja template in an if statement.

```
{% if (value|int =["1", "2", "3", "4"]) %}
{% include 'pages/page1.html' %}
{% else %}
{% include 'pages/page2.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

But this shows the error,

```
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ')', got '='
```

I thought I had to convert json to int in order to make it work.

Comment: `if` is not a loop, it is a conditional statement. `for` is a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jinja2 `int` filter will fail on your list as it will be trying to cast it to a single integer value. Therefore it will return `0`. Also `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is a comparator. Try this to get the intended result:

```
{% if value|join("|") == "1|2|3|4|5"  %}
{% include 'pages/page1.html' %}
{% else %}
{% include 'pages/page2.html' %}
{% endif %}
```